# Validity of Equality in the Condition for a Rational to be a Convergent

Tags: number-theory, inequality, diophantine-approximation

> Let $x$ be an irrational number and the rational number $/$ satisfy the inequality:
> $$
> \bigg|−\frac{a}{b}\bigg|<\frac{1}{2b^2}
> $$
> Then $/$ is a convergent of $x$

A proof by contradiction is given in [Condition for Rational to be a Convergent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Condition_for_Rational_to_be_a_Convergent).

But another proof is given in my reference for the case when $x$ is rational, [Page 637,638, Appendix 4 : Number Theory, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), an equal sign is present in the equality, i.e.,
$$
\bigg|−\frac{a}{b}\bigg|\leq\frac{1}{2b^2}
$$
Going through both the proofs I think equality is valid in the expression. I'd appreciate any help to validate it ?

Thanks @JohnOmielan for the hint.

Can I extend the proof by contradiction to the case when $x$ is rational and add an equal sign to the condition ?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Right. I think it is possible in the case when $x$ is rational which is what the mentioned proof is about. First proof assumes $x$ is irrational. That is why a difference in equality sign.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Done. Can I extend the proof by contradiction to rational $x$ also and include an equal sign ?